# Batch Im trying to make a code that loops a specific amount of times. It will only loop infinitely

Tags: loops, batch-file, if-statement

```
@echo on 
set name=1
:loop
IF "%name%"=="1" (
echo name is 1
pause
set /a %name%=%name%+1
goto loop
) else (
done
pause
)
```

This is the code. It is batch. I am trying to make a script that will loop a specific amount of times, and then echo that its done.

Comment: Why not use a FOR /L command.

Comment: Try `Set/A name+=1`

Answer (score 0):

```
set /a %name%=%name%+1
```

This will set the *contents* of `name` to the *contents* of name + 1.

```
set /a name=%name%+1
```

will do what you require

```
set /a name=name+1
```

is also supported syntax.

Be careful! - `%name%` is not necessarily the *current* contents of `name` - it's actually the contents of `name` *at the time that the* code block* (parenthesised sequence of lines) was entered. See endless SO items about `delayed expansion` for more info...

Answer (score 0):

An example of the above...

```
@echo off
set /a timer=0 | timeout -t 1 /nobreak>nul
:timerStart
echo This should echo 6 times.
set /a timer=%timer%+1
if %timer% leq 5 goto timerStart
if %timer%==6 goto nextPart
:nextPart
echo Thats all folks :P
exit
```

Hope this helps!